# GWT with hot-swap agent and SDM

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gwt, hotswap

I am building a sample GWT project in Intellij. The problem is the code change in my services module is not reflected in the webapp.

Following is the structure of my project:

---

Parent POM:

```
<modules>
    <module>gwt-widgets</module>
    <module>gwt-core</module>
    <module>gwt-services</module>
    <module>gwt-rpc</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

---

gwt-core: which is a web app:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<artifactId>gwt-core</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-widgets</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-widgets</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope><!-- use for compilation only -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-rpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-rpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.tuannguyen.widgets.Widgets</module>
                    <module>com.tuannguyen.example.Examples</module>
                    <module>com.tuannguyen.example.Services</module>
                </modules>
                <runTarget>gwtia-ch04-widgets.html</runTarget>
                <compileSourcesArtifacts>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>com.tuannguyen.gwt:gwt-widgets</compileSourcesArtifact>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>com.tuannguyen.gwt:gwt-services</compileSourcesArtifact>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>com.tuannguyen.gwt:gwt-rpc</compileSourcesArtifact>
                </compileSourcesArtifacts>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**</warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.RC0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Examples.gwt.xml: Module in gwt-core

```
<module rename-to="Examples">
<!-- inherit the standard User module as all GWT applications must -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.tuannguyen.widgets.Widgets'/>
<inherits name='com.tuannguyen.example.Services'/>

<!-- Use the standard theme for widgets -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>

<!-- note the entry point for the application -->
<entry-point class='com.tuannguyen.example.client.Examples'/>

<!-- Indicate where the code that should be translated to Javascript can be found.
     By default this is in the client package, but we indicate that explicitly in
     this example, just to introduce the tag. -->
<source path='client'/>
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" />
```

---

gwt-services:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tuannguyen.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-rpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

gwt-widgets which is a gwt module used in gwt-core:

```
dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some problems:

1. I run the super dev mode in gwt-core using mvn clean install, mvn gwt:run-codeserver and mvn jetty:run-exploded and the web app was built successfully. However, changes in gwt-widgets are not reflected when I recompile the gwt-core with 'Dev Mode On' bookmarklet. If I run the web app using Intellij Run Configuration then it works correctly.
2. I created the following hotswap-agent.properties file in the folder src/main/resources of gwt-core. However, changes in gwt-services are not picked up by the web app when I recompile the class fileg. The content of my properties file is: extraClasspath=gwt-services/target/classes

Is there any solution to these problems?

Comment: The hotswap agent won't provide an update of the SDM resources. It appears that only hot swaps bytecode. I'd suggest generating a maven project this gwt maven plugin here: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes.